# Can I use Ethernet UTP instead of COAX for satellite TV

Tags: ethernet, coax, twisted-pair

I'm planning on having a satellite TV subscription installed on my home, when the satellite dish is installed they will need to run a coax cable from the satellite dish all the way to the decoder beside my TV. I do not like this situation because it will involve drilling holes on quite a few walls just to reach the decoder.

dish -> coax -> decoder

With that I had a idea, since the house is already kitted with ethernet UTP on all rooms, and there is an Ethernet wall plate directly behind the TV, I was thinking running the signal via that UTP and have a passive adaptor like [these ones](https://www.google.com/search?q=rj45%20to%20coax&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5ovDrlPzwAhVM7GEKHRpuBEUQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1536&bih=750#imgrc=pJ7nI-HgrO4PsM). So instead having to drill holes on many of my walls, I will only need to drill one hole. The "server room" where all Ethernet wiring of the house goes to is just 1 wall away from the satellite dish location

dish ->  coax -> adaptor -> ethernet -> adaptor -> coax -> decoder

Will this idea work?

Comment: it may be possible to capture the video output of the satellite receiver and stream it on lan

Comment: HDMI over UTP exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it would not work over CAT cabling.
If it did, everyone would already use CAT cabling for that.

CAT cabling cannot pass the frequencies needed for satellite signals which is why coax is used to begin with.

The adapter you present is not a balun, and CAT cabling has 100 ohm differential impedance while coax uses 50 ohm single-ended impedance, so there is an impedance mismatch, off by a factor of 2.

Comment: If i do use a balun adapter will it now work? judging from a quick search of what is a balun, i think i can still work with it because its still a passive adapater. If it does work are there notable downsides of doing it this way?

Comment: Notable downsides still are that CAT cabling can't pass signal frequencies as required for satellite communications which is why coax is used to begin with.

Comment: thats unfortunate. I just realized that the active solution are for ethernet over coax and not the other way around. Do coax over ethernet solutions exist?

Comment: @DrakeJest they can't, as Justme explained!

Answer (score 1):

It won't work over CAT cabling, satellite dishes use frequencies in the 1000MHz to 2000MHz band, this is far above what ordinary CAT cabling can work with.
(the actual transmissions are at even higher frequencies, the LNB does frequency conversion)

Well, it might work with CAT8 if you have that installed, and can find a 2GHz balun, and a bias tee for each end.